# The set of linear maps between vector spaces form a vector space, and the set of abelian group homomorphisms form an abelian group - general fact?

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, category-theory

I was recently thinking about maps between mathematical objects $f,g:X\to Y$ which have some binary operation for which we can form a new map $f+g:X\to Y$, examples including

- if $X$ and $Y$ are vector spaces, we can add two linear transformations via $(f+g)(x)=f(x)+f(y)$ using the addition on $X$. Furthermore, the set of all linear maps $X\to Y$ form a vector space.
- if $X$ and $Y$ are abelian groups, we can add two group homomorphisms $f$ and $g$ to get a new group homomorphism $(f+g)(x)=f(x)+g(x)$ in the same way, and the set of homomorphisms form an abelian group.

Is there a name for this concept? What is the minimal structure the objects $X$ and $Y$ need to have? I considered monoidal categories, but, we are combining morphisms between objects, not the objects themselves. I also considered things like the [dual space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_space), but this involves maps from the vector space to its underlying field, not between vector spaces.

Comment: Well, there is a notion of an Abelian category, but that's weaker than the case of vector spaces you mention. Of course, in sets, the collection of functions $X\to Y$ is a set. This can be generally stated as "there is an internal Hom functior.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Abelian category was almost right - a slightly weaker notion appears to be [preadditive category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preadditive_category), of which vector spaces are indeed an example!

Comment: Another concept to look into would be "monoidal closed category", which is a category which gives for each pair of objects $X, Y$ an internal hom $[X, Y]$ - and then, there's also a "product" operation $\otimes$ with reasonable properties, and a relation between the two of a natural isomorphism $\operatorname{Hom}(A \otimes B, C) \simeq \operatorname{Hom}(A, [B, C])$.  In the case of the category of $R$-modules (which incidentally also includes both of your cases) the $\otimes$ is exactly the usual tensor product $A \otimes_R B$.

Comment: Another example of a monoidal closed category would be $\mathbf{Set}$ with $[X, Y]$ the set $Y^X$ of functions $f : X \to Y$, and $\otimes$ given by the cartesian product.  (And more generally, if $C$ is any small category, then the category of functors $C \to \mathbf{Set}$ is also a "cartesian closed category", i.e. a monoidal closed category with $\otimes$ given by the categorical product.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Thomas Andrews' comment: the correct idea (with minimal assumptions) seems to be [preadditive category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preadditive_category), or Ab-category:

> a preadditive category is another name for an Ab-category, i.e., a category that is enriched over the category of abelian groups, Ab. That is, an Ab-category C is a category such that every hom-set Hom(A,B) in C has the structure of an abelian group, and composition of morphisms is bilinear...

with examples including abelian groups and vector spaces.